# Wildfly 8.2 - ScriptEngineManager.getEngineFactories is empty on server startup

Tags: javascript, java-8, wildfly-8, rhino

I am facing a weird behavior with Wildfly 8.2.1 running on Java 8 (Open JDK). I am specifically mentioning Java 8, because I did not see this issue on Java 7.

While my Wildfly module is being started, I have code that loads up JavaScripts using the Java RhinoScriptEngine.

```
    List<ScriptEngineFactory> engineFactories = engineManager.getEngineFactories();
    ScriptEngine scriptEngine = engineManager.getEngineByName("js");
```

Since `scriptEngine` was being assigned as `null`, I added debug logs and noticed that `engineFactories` is just an empty `List`(well, the `engineFactories` itself is being fetched only for debugging purposes). But, after the startup of the module is complete, this exact code works, and lists the `RhinoScriptEngineFactory`.

Is there something that has been changed in Java 8 that Wildfly 8.2 is not aware of, or do I need to add explicit dependencies to my module?

Comment: You may have to use `"nashorn"` instead of `"js"`. Or, I think, `"javascript"` may work for both Rhino and Nashorn. Sorry to not be more definitive; I'm trying to see what my own code does.

Comment: But, the same code works perfectly, via another functionality in the application, after the startup is complete. And it does use the Rhino engine.

Comment: Yes that seems odd.

Comment: Which moment do you exec engineManager.getEngineFactories() ?

Comment: Immediately after the server is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script engine manager uses the [service provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) mechanism to enumerate all the implementations of ScriptEngineFactory. ScriptEngineFactory service descriptions are searched in resources accessible from

1. Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() - when construct ScriptEngnineManage without parameter
2. Bootrap class loader - when construct ScriptEngnineManager with null parameter
3. Class loader - when construct swith specific class loader

How do you create ScriptEngineManager?

If you construct ScriptEngineManager without parameters: What return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() when module is booting and when module boot is completed?

Can you attach (upload to pastebin or somewhere) module.xml for you module?

In java 8 rhino script engine was replaced by nashorn script engine. Do you really get RhinoScriptEngineFactory after module is loaded? Or it is NashornScriptEngine?

Comment: It had to do with class loading. So, there were 2 issues - i) the rhino jars were part of another jboss module that my module depended on, this explained why it worked after the server startup was complete. ii) I was not passing the ClassLoader and it was using the current thread contexts loader, and apparently it did not have visibility to the dependent modules classes. I passed the ClassLoader that was used by a class that was a part of my module and it worked.